# unsupported pseudo: -webkit-autofill

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect fields that are autofilled by chrome in js.
The following will throw an exception

```
_isAutofilled: function () {
    if (this.el.find(':-webkit-autofill').length > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
},
```

*Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: -webkit-autofill*

This will throw either:

```
$('input:-webkit-autofill')
```

Is there a clean way to prevent jquery from throwing, even though the pseudo selector is not supported in FF?

I don't want to integrate feature detection and I can't use `try/catch` either.

jQuery Version: 2.2.4

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use `try/catch`? That's the easiest way to check if a browser supports a particular pseudo-selector, since non-support results in throwing an error, which will be caught.

Comment: It belongs to my companies coding standards. Once you wrap something in try/catch, you won't have meaningful errors if something else breaks.

Comment: Those standards don't make sense: I know `try/catch` can be abused, but in this case it is the most straightforward way of checking for pseudo-selector support. It's akin to saying `while` loops can iterate indefinitely so we ban them.

Comment: that might be true but I can't really start arguing there now. Can you think of another solution?

Comment: _“I want to detect fields that are autofilled”_ - what’s the purpose of this?

Comment: @CBroe see https://github.com/Baedda/floating-form-labels/issues/12

Comment: So what you got here is basically another reason to add to the list of https://medium.com/simple-human/floating-labels-are-a-bad-idea-82edb64220f6 ;-)

Comment: @JamesHill the question in the duplicate is about checking general feature support (box-shadow in that case), but here the question is about which specific elements `:-webkit-autofill` actually applies to … So I don’t think that solution from over there can be applied here.

Comment: `check.style['webkitAutoFill']` will always return undefined

Comment: @CBroe, you could be right. I didn't know that I could gold-badge reopen also, but I do now. I removed the dupe close. Having said that, feature support of some kind seems to be the only way to solve this...